Db board in my cottage is connected to the main house db board
I live in a cottage which has a db board this is connected to the main house db board but everytime they switch on the stove in the house it trips in the cottage but has no effect in the main house.how can I solve this problem??

Not enough information, but sounds like something is connected wrong.  A electrician might be your best bet to find out.

Vtc — we aren’t mindreaders here. Either add detail or get an electrician.

What is a db board?  That slang is not something common to my area that I recognize.
